# Pre May 2013 Tripp Trapp differences?

Tags: eating, shopping

I've just purchased a brand new Tripp Trapp chair (in the UK) but the date on the chair indicates it was made in March 2013. Annoyingly the extended gliders in the baby set I purchased at the same time only fit models made after May 2013. Hopefully the retailer can get the right gliders, but should I insist on a newer model, or is the glider fitting the only real difference?

Comment: Downvoted since it is about a specific product. 
That said, we have 2 tripp trapps, one from 2011, one from fall 2013 (manufacturer dates unknown) and they have different gliders, but are otherwise the same. Btw the gilders came in the box, not sure what you need extra for.

Comment: @Ida Plenty of Stack Exchange sites allow asking about specific products - is Parenting SE different? Will delete question if so. Manufacturer date is on the bottom of the chair, and the gliders came with the baby set, not with the chair.

Comment: I know that asking for product recommendation is considered off topic (since they are rapidly outdated) - I may not be right that this is off topic too. Where are you located? I think they may not ship the gliders with the chair everywhere, but both of ours came with them (in the US).

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic, largely because there can be no "right" answer. The continual introduction of new, better products also makes it hard to keep such questions current. This, however, is asking about a specific product, and I don't see that it would suffer from those same issues to a degree that would make this off-topic.

Comment: @Beofett Removing downvote, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I did the same thing. I never knew... Guess I'll learn...

Comment: Could you contact the manufacturer? Hopefully they'll send you the accessories you need free of charge.

Comment: Upvoted to counter product-specific downvote :-) Perhaps @Ida does not realize that the Tripp Trapp is almost as ubiquitous as Ikea? Honestly, look in _any_ home in Europe and you'll be nearly certain to find one.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I think Ida removed the downvote already :)  Tripp Trapp is not something we're familiar with in the US I don't think but I think that doesn't matter a lot in its validness as a question.  It's fine because it's asking for concrete help with something - not a recommendation.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I did remove the downvote when Beofertt explained. I do know Tripp Trapp is ubiquitious, but I thought products were off topic, when they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case **I wouldn't insist on a new model** instead of the one you already received. I am confident that the retailer can get the correct gliders for you, and that'll resolve the matter for you.

---

There have been minor evolutionary changes to the Tripp Trapp over the past 40 years that I've known the product. Amazingly, put an ancient one next to a brand-new one and you can barely tell them apart.

The biggest change is that the infant seat is no longer a vertical leather strap, secured between a slit in the seat and a wooden horizontal bar. That strap and bar has now been replaced by a molded plastic shape.

The gliders you refer to is a relatively new addition, too. They're only needed while the child is small, to prevent the chair from tipping backward. Apparently they changed the distance of the mounting holes. I guess that product changes are only made in order to adapt to newer safety regulations, but I can't think why the hole distance would have to change.